# Odoo restrict delete of record that is still referenced (m2m)

Tags: constraints, odoo, odoo-8

I have this field:

```
range_application_ids = fields.Many2many('insurance.commission.rule.range.application', 'application_rule_range_rel', 'rule_range_id',
    'application_id', 'Applications', ondelete='restrict', required=True)
```

I need to restricts delete of that models (`insurance.commission.rule.range.application`) records if it is referenced through Many2many relation. Now if I go to that models records list and delete any of it, Odoo won't throw any warning and lets me do it. Then when I got to another models record that has relation with `insurance.commission.rule.range.application` through many2many field, I see that it was removed (and that field is required). Setting `ondelete='restrict'` did not do anything.

Is there a way to restrict such deletes with Odoo standard functionality or I need to implement such checking myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I implemented such constraint myself, but if anyone know how to do it using standard methods, please post another answer. Here is the code (it goes in `insurance.commission.rule.range.application` model (or class in other words):

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    range_obj = self.env['insurance.commission.rule.range']
    rule_ranges = range_obj.search([('range_application_ids', 'in', self.ids)])
    if rule_ranges:
        raise Warning(_("You are trying to delete a record that is still referenced!"))
    return super(insurance_commission_rule_range_application, self).unlink()
```

Comment: You got any other way ? I also have the same need.
I refered how Odoo is preventing Product Categories from being deleted.
But I can't understand where it is done.